# I am facing Java.lang.nosuchFeildExecption , While executing

Tags: java

I am facing this Java.lang.nosuchFeildExecption
while executing the code..
Can anyone help me in this, How can Resolve this Issue??
Thanks in Advance 
I am facing this Java.lang.nosuchFeildExecption
while executing the code..

```
    public class Validation {
    public void readJSON() throws Exception {
            File file = new File("myJSONFile.txt");
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");

            // Convert JSON string to JSONObject
            JSONObject tomJsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
            System.out.println(tomJsonObject);
            System.out.println(tomJsonObject.getString("age"));
            validateByType(tomJsonObject, "age", null);
        }

        public void validateByType(JSONObject jsonString, String pathString, String typeString)
                throws JSONException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
            String jsonField = jsonString.getString(pathString);
            // pathString = "age";
            // typeString ="number";

            Class<?> c = Class.forName("Validation");
            Field f = c.getField(jsonField);
            System.out.format("Type: %s%n", f.getType());
            System.out.format("GenericType: %s%n", f.getGenericType());

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Test");
            Validation v = new Validation();
            try {
                v.readJSON();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Its obvious that the system is not able to find "myJSONFile.txt" file, try putting the json file in resources folder of project and use relative path.

Comment: Ya I have  given that relative path only But the issues is with this----
Class<?> c = Class.forName("Validation");
            Field f = c.getField(jsonField);
            System.out.format("Type: %s%n", f.getType());
            System.out.format("GenericType: %s%n", f.getGenericType());

Answer (score 0):

Give path
For Eg: File file = new File("D:\myJSONFile.txt");
OR give your path according to your requirement
In windows machine
String absoluteFilePath = fileSeparator+"Users"+fileSeparator+"roopesh"+fileSeparator+"myJSONFile.txt";
 File file = new File(absoluteFilePath);

Comment: It won't work if he decides to run this on a different machine.

Comment: I gave just an example.. According to his machine or project structure requirement he should give path 
For Eg: In windows machine ::String absoluteFilePath = fileSeparator+"Users"+fileSeparator+"roopesh"+fileSeparator+"file.txt";
File file = new File(absoluteFilePath);

Comment: Ya I have  given that path only But the issues is with this----
Class<?> c = Class.forName("Validation");
            Field f = c.getField(jsonField);
            System.out.format("Type: %s%n", f.getType());
            System.out.format("GenericType: %s%n", f.getGenericType());

Answer (score 0):

The file can be added (assuming it can be) to **src/main/resources** folder, and then use java.nio package to read the file:

```
 Path path = Path.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myJSONFile.txt").toURI());
 byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
 String theString = new String(fileBytes, "UTF-8");
```

Now to read the class and field:

```
 Class<?> c = Class.forName("<give class name with package>");

 //whatever field is attempted to be read
 Field f = c.getDeclaredField("fieldName");
```

This field should be present in the class.

Example:

```
 private String fieldName;
```

Comment: Ya I have  given that path only But the issues is with this----
Class<?> c = Class.forName("Validation");
            Field f = c.getField(jsonField);
            System.out.format("Type: %s%n", f.getType());
            System.out.format("GenericType: %s%n", f.getGenericType());

Comment: I updated the answer, see if it helps to answer your query on reflection

Comment: Also exception name in your question is wrong. java.lang.NoSuchFieldException should be thrown then.

Comment: I have like this  --- Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.sample.validation.Validation");
  Field f = c.getDeclaredField(jsonField); 
  System.out.format("Type: %s%n", f.getType());
  System.out.format("GenericType: %s%n", f.getGenericType());
  }
-----------------------
but still facing same issue---
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: age
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
 at com.sample.validation.Validation.validateByType(Validation.java:47)
 at com.sample.validation.Validation.readJSON(Validation.java:34)
 at com.sample.validation.Validation.main(Validation.java:62)

Comment: What is the value of jsonField. Lets say if it is "name" is name defined in the class-com.sample.validation.Validation. I dont see any fields in your class.

Comment: Try adding in your class : private int age = 10; and see if works ?

Comment: If I add like this private int age = 10;  It giving me Illegal modifier for parameter age...

Comment: Dont add within method, add it at class level

Comment: Yup I added at class level but still facing same issue